# Android: seekbar inside SwipeRefreshLayout inside Viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, touch, swiperefreshlayout, android-seekbar

I have a ViewPager containing numbers of Fragment.

In each Fragment, there is a SwipeRefreshLayout which is containin a seek bar.

However, the seek bar thumb is not moved smoothly(horizontally direction).

The thumb always move some percentage of progress of seek bar and the release touch automatically even I am still touch the thumb.

Does anyone faced same case?

How could it fix it?

Answer (score 4):

@robxyy answer is correct but it took me while to figure out implementation pieces. Hence, to elaborate his answer. Please see below code:

```
public class CustomSwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {
    private int mTouchSlop;
    private float mPrevX;
    private boolean isDisabled;

    public CustomSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).getScaledTouchSlop();
    }

    public void disableInterceptTouchEvent(boolean isDisabled) {
        this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(isDisabled);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mPrevX = MotionEvent.obtain(event).getX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (isDisabled) {
                    return false;
                }
                float eventX = event.getX();
                float xDiff = Math.abs(eventX - mPrevX);
                if (xDiff > mTouchSlop) {
                    return false;
                }
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Above class is extending swipe refresh layout. Now we need to call

```
disableInterceptTouchEvent(true)
```

when we start Seekbar swiping and we need to call

```
disableInterceptTouchEvent(false)
```

When Seekbar swiping stop. Hence, Custom Seekbar class looks like:

```
public class SwipeView extends RelativeLayout implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    private CustomSwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    public SwipePromotionView(CustomSwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout) {
        this.swipeRefreshLayout = swipeRefreshLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
          // include some logic here to decide which part of the swipe bar is a valid starting point
        swipeRefreshLayout.disableInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        swipeRefreshLayout.disableInterceptTouchEvent(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend SwipeRefreshLayout, then override onInterceptTouchEvent method.

```
    public void disableInterceptTouchEvent(boolean isDisabled) {
        this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(isDisabled);
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mPrevX = MotionEvent.obtain(event).getX();
            break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (isDisabled) {
              return false;
            }
            float eventX = event.getX();
            float xDiff = Math.abs(eventX - mPrevX);
            if (xDiff > mTouchSlop) {
              return false;
            }
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }
```